# Как получить нажатую клавишу в FreePascal?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Пишу курсовой по паскалю, вкратце задание: на шахматной доске разместить ферзей, проверить, чтобы не били друг друга.

Реализовал: по шахматной доске по нажатию стрелок передвигается курсор, в указанном месте по нажатию Enter должна рисоваться фигура, но на нажатие Enter программа не реагирует, как и на любые другие указанные там клавиши.

В чем может быть проблема?

FreePascal 3.0.4

```
procedure move_ferz(n: integer);
var
  k: char;
  x, y: integer;
begin
  x := 1;
  y := 1;
  repeat
    k := ReadKey;
    if ord(k) = 0 then
    begin
      k := ReadKey;
      case ord(k) of
        77: if x <> n then inc(x);
        75: if x <> 1 then dec(x);
        72: if y <> 1 then dec(y);
        80: if y <> n then inc(y);
        13: draw_ferz(x, y);
      end;
    end;
  until (ord(k) = 27);
end;
```

Comment: коды клавиш указаны правильно, почему-то case не хочет Enter обрабатывать

Comment: посмотри сюда и сравни https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/crt/readkey.html

Comment: для клавиши Enter (k:=13), использование ord(k) равносильно использованию #13. Поэтому тут ошибки быть не должно

Comment: `Enter` генерирует только один символ `#13`, а не `#0#13`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прекрасно работает

```
program keypressing;

uses crt;
var
    ch: char;
BEGIN   
    repeat
        ch := ReadKey;
        case ch of
            #0:
                begin
                    ch := ReadKey;
                    case ch of
                        #75: WriteLn('Left');
                        #72: WriteLn('Up');
                        #77: WriteLn('Right');
                        #80: WriteLn('Down');
                    end;
                end;
            #13: WriteLn('Enter');
            #27: WriteLn('Esc');
        end;
    until ch = #27;
END.
```

Comment: Спасибо, так и правда работает. Если не сложно, могли бы объяснить почему мой вариант не сработал?

Comment: @Meloman_ze код из вопроса тоже запустился и работает, единственное замечание, как отметил @extrn, `Enter` генерирует только #13, без первого 0, значит его нужно вынести за пределы `if ord(k) = 0`, т.е. нужен еще один `if ord(k) = 13 then draw_ferz(x, y);`

Comment: понял, буду знать